# How can I add the _locale parameter to security paths?

Tags: security, symfony, internationalization, routes, authorization

I setup my security settings to protect everything which is under the root path `/`, exept for a public page to view the privacy policy, `/privacy`. Everything works fine.

```
# security.yml
access_control:
    - { path: ^/privacy$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/,         role: ROLE_USER }
```

Now I added some different translations to the privacy policy page, so that the route changes from `/privacy` to `/{_locale}/privacy`. Unfortunately I cannot add the `_locale` parameter to the security path like this:

```
access_control:
    ...
    - { path: ^/{_locale}/privacy$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

So how do I have to modify my `security.yml` so that I can add the `_locale` to the path and to restrict it to predefined languages, e.g. `(en|fr|es|de)`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Nowadays (since Symfony 4.1 or later) you can define the locales in one place and use it everywhere in your application

in `config/services.yaml` add

```
parameters:
    myAppName.locales: en|fr|es|de
```

in `config/routes.yaml`

```
cms:
    prefix:   /{_locale}/
    controller: App\Controller\DefaultController::index
    requirements:
        _locale: '%myAppName.locales%'
```

in `config/packages/security.yaml`

```
security:
    ## .... no changes here
    access_control:
        - { path: ^/(%myAppName.locales%)/cms, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

Comment: I'm glad they added this feature. Thanks for the update!

Answer (score 9):

If all your locales are 2-character ones (`en|fr|es|de|...`) you can use a more generic regex like this:

```
- { path: '^/[a-z]{2}/privacy$', role: 'IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY' }
```

This way you won't have to touch your `security.access_control` every time you add a new locale.

For locales in the form `EN_en` you could use something like this btw:

```
- { path: '^/[a-zA-Z]{2}_[a-zA-Z]{2}/privacy$', role: 'IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY' }
```

Comment: Hi, nice idea, but I would like to restrict it to a predefined array of languages.

Comment: Can you imagine any case where a route like `/de/privacy` shall be public instead of restricted in another language? if yes you could just add this exact url pattern on top of the `access_control` list to overcome this situation. There is no security risk involved - its even faster.

Comment: You're right, not defined languages for the `_locale` are blocked by the firewall, so there's no need to define languages in this security path. Thanks!

Comment: What would be the regex where both, `en` and `EN_en` are allowed?

Comment: I har to quote the route: `- { path: '^/[a-z]{2}/privacy$', role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }`. (Using Symfony 2.8.)

Comment: If you don't quote the route as @YngveHøiseth suggested, `}` character terminates the path definition and Symfony throws an exception.

Comment: Note: In Symfony 4 you can't use this kind of regex in the access_control, it throws an "invalid yaml"-error (while "(en|es)" works).

Answer (score 8):

I managed to solve the problem like this

```
access_control:
    ...
    - { path: ^/(en|fr|es|de)/privacy$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

---

A recommendation for other answerers: I now have to enter this string `(en|fr|de)` into all routes manually. When I add a language I have to modifiy this string in many occurences. It would be much better if one could define a string

```
parameters:
    languages: "(en|fr|es|de)"
```

And use this in the route

```
    - { path: ^/%languages%/privacy$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

But I don't think this will work.

Comment: I've not found a way; YML doesn't really support string concatenation.

Comment: I tried with `languages: "(en|fr)"` and `- { path: ^/%languages%/admin, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }`. There is no error but all the languages are accepted, even `es` or `de`.

Comment: Yes, the YAML parser should trigger an exception, or the router should stop working.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue and I resolve it by making some changes to the pattern in my secure area in firewalls setting. And then updating the access controls. The code is below

```
 firewalls:

    # disables authentication for assets and the profiler, adapt it according to your needs
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    admin_area:
        context: admin_area
        anonymous: ~
        pattern: ^/(en|ar)/admin/*
        form_login:
            login_path: admin_login
            check_path: admin_login
            default_target_path: admin_home
            provider: admins
        logout:
            path: admin_logout
            target: admin_login
```

below is the access_controll

```
    access_control:
    - { path: ^/(en|ar)/admin/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/(en|ar)/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
    - { path: ^/, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

Comment: Further if you add the app_locales in the config.yml file as belowparameters:
    app_locales: en|ar then you will be able to acces it via  - { path: ^/(%app_locales%)/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN } or  pattern: ^/(%app_locales%)/admin/*