# How to let Symfony 2 adopt the protocol scheme (http vs https)

Tags: php, http, symfony, https

I have a Symfony 2 website that either runs on HTTP in development or on HTTPS in production.

I noticed that in production the URL's generated by Symfony are still all rendered as HTTP.

How can I either;

1. Let the framework adopt the current protocol from which the website is served (probably preferred)?
2. Or, force the entire website in HTTPS mode only in production?

Comment: How do you generate the URLs? With `{{ path() }}`?

Comment: I'm using `{{ url(' ... ') }}` in my Twig templates.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Both solutions given by @A.L and @AndreySobkanyuk are valid, but don't apply to the issue I was experiencing.

The problem with both solutions given by @A.L and @AndreySobkanyuk is that Symfony 2 is trying to do a redirect. I.e. if a URL is accessed through a protocol (e.g. HTTP) which in the routing config is specified differently (e.g. HTTPS), Symfony 2 will do a redirect (at a PHP level).

In my situation, the URL rewriting happens at a web server level (Apache) because my website serves all URL's as HTTPS.

The problem I was dealing with was that the URL's generated in my templates were all rendered using the HTTP protocol were they should have been HTTPS. I was assuming that there was a way to tell Symfony that whenever it renders a URL to prefix it with HTTPS instead of HTTP. Unfortunately, there isn't (or at least, not that I'm aware off).

Since my website is running behind a load balancer, my web server wasn't aware that it should render URL's as HTTPS because the internal connection between the load balancer and the web server is HTTP. This means that from Symfony's point of view, all requests are made using HTTP and by forcing the protocol on a Symfony routing level, it was causing an infinite redirect loop, i.e;

1. You hit a URL through HTTPS.
2. The load balancer passes the request to the web server as HTTP.
3. Within Symfony the route is configured to use HTTPS which causes a redirect at a PHP level.
4. Back to 1 (infinite loop).

To solve my problem I had to make my web server aware of the fact that my website runs in HTTPS. By following the instructions given on the [How to Configure Symfony to Work behind a Load Balancer or a Reverse Proxy](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/request/load_balancer_reverse_proxy.html) page I as able to fix the problem, i.e. my web server is now being supplied with the correct header information and is now generating the correct URL's.

The easiest way to pass on the required headers from the load balancer to the web server is to add the following line to your `web/app.php`:

```
Request::setTrustedProxies(array($request->server->get('REMOTE_ADDR')));
```

Beware, that the above might not be the best solution for your specific configuration. Please refer to the documentation for other approaches that might be more suitable for your set up.

Comment: I always test the code before posting my answers, so I checked `schemes: [https]` with `resource` and it was working good for me.

Comment: And all my ulrs generated with `{{ url() }}` are `https` based.

Comment: @AndreySobkanyuk; Are you behind a load-balancer? It's probably working for you because you're not behind a load-balancer. Before I understood the problem I was assuming that your solution forced rendering of HTTPS URL's but it does not. It forces a redirect at a PHP level to a HTTPS URL when hitting the URL with HTTP, for me this caused an infinite redirect loop.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't help you with your load balancer and this is another question. And of course when you try to access `http` based url `Symfony` tries to redirect you. **BUT** at least as I've already said your urls generated with `url()` extension must be `https` based if you are using my solution. If your urls are not `https` based then you are doing it wrong.

Comment: Check that you are generating absolute url and haven't set the `schemeRelative` parameter as `true`: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/5bb2816b0f0300c2143f25d0cd82de2831b94abb/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Extension/RoutingExtension.php#L50

Comment: Thanks Andrey for your help, but you don't understand the question I was asking. In my question I'm trying to find a way to tell Symfony to always render my URL's in my templates to be HTTPS. Your answer is a way to "redirect" a URL when it is accessed, i.e. from HTTP to HTTPS, your answer doesn't apply to the rendering of URL's in templates. I hope my answer explains the difference.

Comment: Can you please post the full solution? This answer is a "link-only" at this moment.

Comment: Yeah, seams we are answering to the different questions :) Anyway glad you've the solution.

Comment: Ho after digging into this if you want https behind a reverse proxy /lb and twig render url / asset in https schemes you have to forward both scheme and port

Answer (score 7):

I found this useful for my case (using **nginx**)

add to nginx fcgi params the following line, This is needed because Symfony2 relies on this variable, passed by the web server to PHP, to generate the correct URL. *Apache does this by default, but nginx needs this special config*.

`fastcgi_param HTTPS on;`

http://blog.servergrove.com/2011/04/04/symfony2-quick-tip-generateurl-with-https-on-nginx/

Answer (score 5):

To force `HTTPS` in your production environment you can use the following configuration:

1. In your `app/config/routing.yml`:

   ```
   acme_hello:
       resource: "@AcmeHelloBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
       schemes: [https]
   ```
2. In your add `app/config/routing_dev.yml`:

   ```
   _main:
       resource: routing.yml
       schemes: [http]
   ```

   if you want to force `HTTP` for all your routes in development environment.
3. And in your `@AcmeHelloBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml` you can place all your routes.

For more information about `schemes: [https]` and other ways to make it work you can look at [Symfony documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/routing/scheme.html).

Comment: OK. That might work. However, when adding it to a `resource` like you illustrate, doesn't seem to work for me (cache cleared). It's definitely something that has to be controlled by the framework configuration, not individual bundles.

Comment: @Luke the Symfony2 doc says *Symfony will automatically generate an absolute URL with HTTPS as the scheme*, does it work for you? What about this other sentence *path with HTTP [...] will automatically be redirected to the same URL [...] with the HTTPS scheme*?

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work for me. I'm starting to suspect that it might have to do because I'm behind a load-balancer or something. Please understand, it's not that the site doesn't work on HTTPS, it does. It's just the the URL's generated in the templates are HTTP where they should be HTTPS.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming this case :

- Your Symfony app is behind a reverse proxy like Varnish or BigIP
- You want to use original client IP as `REMOTE_ADDR` (i.e with `mod_rpaf` apache extension) (of course in this case you can't use `trusted_proxies` value)

You can set HTTPS environment variable in your webserver, indexed on X-FORWARDED-PROTO header value, to force Symfony to use https protocol.

In Apache :

```
SetEnvIf x-forwarded-proto https HTTPS=on
```

Answer (score 2):

Ho after digging into this if you want https behind a reverse proxy /load balancer and twig render url / asset in https schemes you have to forward both **scheme** and **port**

exemple reverse proxy app.php

```php
Request::setTrustedProxies(array('127.0.0.1), Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_ALL);
```

```
        proxy_pass                           http://localhost:6081;
        proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header  Host              $host;
        proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Port  443;
```

twig

```
<script src="{{ asset('build/common.js') }}"></script>
```

will be `<script src="https://www.example.com/build/common.js"></script>`

Answer (score 1):

I used this solution to force HTTP or HTTPS:

I defined a `%auth_required_channel%` value in the different environments configuration files:

<kbd>app/config/config_dev.yml</kbd> and <kbd>app/config/config_test.yml</kbd>

```yml
parameters:
    auth_required_channel: 'http'
```

<kbd>app/config/config_prod.yml</kbd>

```yml
parameters:
    auth_required_channel: 'https'
```

<kbd>app/config/security.yml</kbd>

This parameter is then used to require the HTTP or HTTPS channel ([Symfony2 documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/force_https.html)):

```yml
security:
    [...]
    access_control:
        [...]
        - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN, requires_channel: %auth_required_channel% }
```

(adapted from an [old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19952258/2257664))

Comment: This would only enforce the protocol on the secured endpoints. I need to enforce in on the entire website. The problem also isn't enforcing the the protocol, it's that not the correct URL's are generated. I.e. I force HTTPS but it's still generating HTTP based URL's.

Comment: Then you have to copy `, requires_channel: %auth_required_channel%` for each line under `security.access_control`. Do you have so many rules? *it's that not the correct URL's are generated* IIRC, the URL generated with `{{ path(...) }}` are relative so the protocol won't be included. And Symfony2 should redirect URLs from `http://` to `https://`.

Comment: You don't understand. Your answer only applies the routes specified for the security bundle, not the rest of the routes I have in my website (i.e. `routing.yml`). I'm sure your example works but it will only apply to those routes defined in the security section, nothing else.

Comment: *Your answer only applies the routes specified for the security bundle* The firewall applies rules to all the rules, it's not linked to a bundle. I don't know if the router knows if a route use HTTP or HTTPS channel. Anyway I just checked with this code and Symfony2 redirects the request from `http://...` to `https://...` in prod environment.

Comment: OK. Then using the security settings, how do I enforce ALL routes on my website to be HTTPS. Not just those behind `/admin`?

Comment: With `- { path: ^/, requires_channel: %auth_required_channel% }` as the last rule maybe? It's hard to say without viewing your `security.yml` file, please add your configuration in your question.

Comment: Tried this (cleared my cache). Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work. All URL in the templates are still generated as HTTP based URL's.

Comment: I think that the URLs are not a problem as long as Symfony2 redirects `http://` to `https://`, see my comment below the other answer.

Comment: My redirecting from HTTP to HTTPS is done at a web server level. I.e. Apache rewrite.

Comment: @Luke: I am having the same problem. I redirected http to https in the .htaccess file, So the redirection is working properly, but the page is not generating https urls. Have you solved this issue? Please let me know. Thanks

Comment: @AjuJohn yes the problem is solved please take a look at accepted answer :)