# Symfony2: Dynamically generate URL protocol (HTTP/HTTPS)

Tags: symfony

I know many ways of forcing a route or a whole section to use either http or https:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/routing/scheme.html

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/force_https.html

[How to let Symfony 2 adopt the protocol scheme (http vs https)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28353864/how-to-let-symfony-2-adopt-the-protocol-scheme-http-vs-https)

...my question is: Is there a way for it to be decided dynamically?

By this, I mean, when I generate the url `{{url('route_name'}}` it generates a URL using the same protocol that the current page is using.

http://domain/index *links to* http://domain/route

https://domain/index *links to* https://domain/route

Comment: By dynamically you mean manually? Because its already dynamic since symfony takes in count what's the current schema for generating the url

Comment: @RenatoMendesFigueiredo At least in my case, it doesn't. In `https://domain/index` the snippet `{{ url('route') }}` prints `http://domain/route` :/

Comment: Do you have a load balancer or proxy in front of your application? Also check the $_SERVER global variable to see if all HTTPS Settings are there